# Has promotion with double check ever happened in a professional game?

Tags: pawn-promotion, master-games, famous-games, double-check

Promotion is common in many games, and is sometimes comes with check. But something I have never seen in a game is a promotion that comes with double check like this example illustrates.

```
[FEN "8/3QPk2/8/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. e8=Q++
```

Has this ever occurred in a professional game? If so, has it happened for each type of promotion? An example that comes with checkmate  would nice as well, but it has probably never happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I was able to locate a game between grandmasters which included a double-check promotion.

```
[Event "17. ch-EUR Indiv 2016"]
[Site "Gjakova KOS"]
[Date "2016.05.19"]
[Round "7.5"]
[White "Ter-Sahakyan, Samvel"]
[Black "Ponomariov, Ruslan"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "2601"]
[BlackElo "2715"]
[ECO "B51"]
[EventDate "2016.05.12"]
[WhiteTitle "GM"]
[BlackTitle "GM"]
[Opening "Sicilian"]
[Variation "Canal-Sokolsky (Nimzovich-Rossolimo, Moscow) attack"]
[WhiteFideId "13302531"]
[BlackFideId "14103320"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "102"]


1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.Bb5+ Nd7 4.O-O a6 5.Bd3 Ngf6 6.Re1 b5 7.c4 g5 8.Nxg5 
Ne5 9.Be2 bxc4 10.Nc3 Bh6 11.Nf3 Nd3 12.Bxd3 cxd3 13.e5 dxe5 14.Nxe5 Kf8 
15.Qf3 Be6 16.Nxd3 Rg8 17.Ne5 Nd5 18.g3 Rc8 19.d3 Bg7 20.Bg5 f6 21.Ng6+ 
hxg6 22.Rxe6 Nb4 23.Be3 Kf7 24.Qe4 Qd7 25.Rb6 Rgd8 26.Rd1 Nxd3 27.Qc4+ Kf8
28.Rxa6 Qf5 29.Qe4 Qxe4 30.Nxe4 c4 31.Nc5 Nxc5 32.Rxd8+ Rxd8 33.Bxc5 f5 
34.Ra4 Rd1+ 35.Kg2 Rc1 36.Rb4 Kf7 37.a4 c3 38.bxc3 Rxc3 39.Bb6 Ra3 40.a5 
Bc3 41.Rb5 Ra2 42.h4 e5 43.Rc5 Bd4 44.Rc7+ Kf6 45.Rc6+ Kg7 46.Bxd4 exd4 
47.a6 d3 48.Kf3 Kh6 49.Ke3 d2 50.Ke2 Kh5 51.Rf6 d1=Q+ 52.Kxd1 Rxf2 53.Kc1 
Rg2 54.a7 Ra2 55.Rf7 Kg4 56.Kb1 Ra5 57.Rg7 Kxg3 58.h5 Rxa7 59.Rxa7 gxh5 
60.Kc2 h4 61.Kd3 h3 62.Ke2 h2 63.Rg7+ Kh3 64.Rh7+ Kg2 65.Rg7+ Kh3 66.Kf2 
h1=N+ 67.Kf3 Kh2 68.Rg2+ Kh3 69.Rg5 Kh2 70.Rxf5 Kg1 71.Rg5+ Kf1 72.Rg2 1-0
```

And here's one where the pawn is promoted to a rook:

```
[Event "2. London Chess Classic"]
[Site "London ENG"]
[Date "2010.12.14"]
[Round "6"]
[White "Kramnik, Vladimir"]
[Black "Carlsen, Magnus"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[WhiteElo "2791"]
[BlackElo "2802"]
[ECO "D07"]
[EventDate "2010.12.06"]
[WhiteTitle "GM"]
[BlackTitle "GM"]
[Opening "QGD"]
[Variation "Chigorin defence"]
[WhiteFideId "4101588"]
[BlackFideId "1503014"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "113"]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 Nc6 3.Nf3 Bg4 4.Nc3 e6 5.Bf4 Bd6 6.Bg3 Nf6 7.e3 O-O 8.a3 Ne7 
9.Qb3 b6 10.Ne5 c5 11.Nxg4 Nxg4 12.Rd1 Bxg3 13.hxg3 Nf6 14.cxd5 exd5 15.
Be2 Qd6 16.Qc2 h6 17.O-O c4 18.b3 Qxa3 19.bxc4 dxc4 20.Bf3 Rab8 21.Ra1 Qd6
22.Nb5 Qd7 23.Qxc4 a5 24.e4 Rfc8 25.Qe2 Rc6 26.Rab1 Rd8 27.Rfd1 Rdc8 28.d5
Rc2 29.Qe3 R2c5 30.Nd4 Re8 31.Qd3 Qd6 32.Qa6 Rb8 33.Nb3 Rc2 34.Nd4 Rc5 35.
Nb3 Rc2 36.Qd3 Rcc8 37.Nd2 Ng6 38.Be2 Qc5 39.Rb5 Qc3 40.f4 a4 41.e5 Nd7 
42.Qxc3 Rxc3 43.Ne4 Rc7 44.Ra1 Ra7 45.d6 Ngf8 46.Nc3 Nc5 47.Nd5 Ra5 48.
Rxb6 Rxb6 49.Nxb6 Nfe6 50.Bc4 Kf8 51.f5 Nd8 52.Rf1 Ncb7 53.Re1 a3 54.e6 
fxe6 55.fxe6 Nxd6 56.e7+ Ke8 57.exd8=R+ Kxd8 58.Rd1 Kc7 59.Ba2 Rg5 60.Nd5+
Kc6 61.Nc3 Rc5 62.Rxd6+ Kxd6 63.Ne4+ Kc6 64.Nxc5 Kxc5 65.Kf2 Kd4 66.Kf3 
Kd3 67.g4 Kd2 68.Be6 Kd3 69.Kg3 Ke3 70.Kh4 Kf2 71.Bd5 g6 72.Kh3 g5 73.Kh2 
Kf1 74.Be6 Kf2 75.Bc4 Ke3 76.Kg3 Kd4 77.Be6 Ke3 78.Kh2 Kf2 79.Bc4 Ke3 80.
Kg1 Kf4 81.Be6 Ke5 82.Bb3 Kf4 83.Be6 Ke5 84.Bb3 Kf4 85.Be6 Ke5 86.Bb3 
1/2-1/2
```

And a bishop:

```
[Event "GMA"]
[Site "Bermuda BER"]
[Date "2003.02.02"]
[Round "8"]
[White "Markowski, Tomasz"]
[Black "Movsesian, Sergei"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "2574"]
[BlackElo "2663"]
[ECO "A09i"]
[EventDate "2003.01.25"]
[PlyCount "113"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "100"]


1.g3 d5 2.Nf3 g6 3.c4 d4 4.Bg2 Bg7 5.O-O c5 6.d3 Nc6 7.Na3 Nf6 8.Nc2 O-O 
9.a3 a5 10.b3 e5 11.Rb1 e4 12.Ng5 exd3 13.exd3 Bg4 14.Qd2 h6 15.h3 Bf5 16.
Nf3 Qc8 17.Kh2 Nd7 18.Nh4 Be6 19.f4 Ne7 20.g4 Qc7 21.Kg1 f5 22.Qe2 Ra6 23.
Bd2 Bf6 24.g5 hxg5 25.fxg5 Be5 26.Nf3 Bg7 27.b4 axb4 28.axb4 Bf7 29.bxc5 
Nc6 30.Rb5 Re8 31.Qf2 Ra2 32.Nfe1 Nde5 33.Qg3 Re7 34.Bf4 Qc8 35.Rb1 Ra5 
36.Na1 Nd7 37.Nb3 Ra2 38.Rf2 Qa8 39.Nc2 Qa4 40.Qf3 Nde5 41.Qd1 Nxd3 42.
Qxd3 Bxc4 43.Qg3 d3 44.Ne3 Bxb3 45.Rxb3 Qxb3 46.Bd5+ Qxd5 47.Nxd5 Re1+ 48.
Kg2 Ree2 49.Rxe2 dxe2 50.Kf2 e1=B+ 51.Kxe1 Ra1+ 52.Kd2 Ra2+ 53.Kd1 Nd4 54.
Nf6+ Bxf6 55.gxf6 Ra1+ 56.Kd2 Ra2+ 57.Kd3 1-0
```

And a knight:

```
[Event "Lake Sevan GM"]
[Site "Martuni ARM"]
[Date "2010.07.11"]
[Round "1"]
[White "Grigoryan, Avetik"]
[Black "Petrosian, Tigran L"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "2584"]
[BlackElo "2597"]
[ECO "D30"]
[EventDate "2010.07.11"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "100"]


1.Nf3 d5 2.d4 c6 3.c4 Nf6 4.e3 e6 5.Bd3 Nbd7 6.Nbd2 dxc4 7.Nxc4 c5 8.O-O 
Be7 9.e4 cxd4 10.e5 Nd5 11.Nxd4 Nc5 12.Bc2 O-O 13.a3 a5 14.Qg4 f5 15.Qg3 
Qe8 16.Bg5 a4 17.Bxe7 Qxe7 18.Rfd1 Ne4 19.Bxe4 fxe4 20.Nd6 e3 21.fxe3 Bd7 
22.Rac1 Bc6 23.h3 h6 24.Kh2 Kh7 25.Rf1 Nb6 26.Nxc6 bxc6 27.Rxf8 Rxf8 28.
Rxc6 Nd5 29.Qg4 Nxe3 30.Qe4+ Nf5 31.g4 Qh4 32.gxf5 Qf2+ 33.Qg2 Qf4+ 34.Kh1
exf5 35.e6 Qe5 36.Nc4 Qe1+ 37.Kh2 Rf6 38.Qg1 Qe4 39.Qg2 Qf4+ 40.Qg3 Qe4 
41.Rc5 Rxe6 42.Qf2 f4 43.h4 f3 44.h5 Qg4 45.Qc2+ Re4 46.Nd6 f2 47.Rf5 Qg1+
48.Kh3 Qg4+ 49.Kh2 Re2 50.Qd3 f1=N+ 0-1
```